# How do i sum column group by different column in Codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, sum, codeigniter-3, cart, checkout

i have a **cart** table like this.. So, i'm trying to sum of the **'weight'** column based on **'id_user'** column.

| id | id_user | id_product | qty | weight | subtotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 6 | 3000 | 399960 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 500 | 41864 |
| 3 | 4 | 7 | 1 | 500 | 136350 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 1500 | 212100 |
| 5 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 1000 | 83728 |

I want the result like this :

| id_user | weight |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3500 |
| 4 | 3000 |

I've tried but the result is not what i want. Here is my code :

My Model

```
public function getSum()
{
    $totalWeight = "SELECT id_user, sum(weight) as weight FROM cart GROUP BY id_user";
    $result = $this->db->query($totalWeight);
    return $result->row()->weight;
}
```

MY Controller

```
public function index() {
   $this->checkout->table  = 'cart';
   $data['totalWeight'] = $this->checkout->getSum();
}
```

The results that I get from the code above like this :

| id_user | weight |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3500 |
| 4 | 3500 |

I don't know why, but every time i try to checkout with a different **quantity(qty)** and a different **id_user**, the results displayed in the weight column are always 3500 or always follow the id_user who did the first checkout process.




I hope you guys understand and can help me to solve my problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your sql query calculates the sum of weights for all users in the table, but your php code retrieves only the first record of the resultset - which is likely to be the user, who first ordered.

If you want to retrieve the sum for a specific user only, then filter your query by `id_user`.

```
public function getSum()
{
    $totalWeight = "SELECT id_user, sum(weight) as weight FROM cart WHERE id_user= ? GROUP BY id_user";
    $result = $this->db->query($totalWeight, array($current_user_id));
    return $result->row()->weight;
}
```

If you want to retrieve the sums for all users, then you need to use the `result()` method of your query results and get the weights in a loop.

```
public function getSum()
{
    $totalWeight = "SELECT id_user, sum(weight) as weight FROM cart GROUP BY id_user WHERE id_user= ?";
    $result = $this->db->query($totalWeight, array($current_user_id));
    return $result->result();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, i think it is worked. But an error appears saying :

**A Database Error Occurred**

**Error Number: 1064**

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id_user= 4' at line 1

SELECT id_user, sum(weight) as weight FROM cart GROUP BY id_user WHERE id_user= 4

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/omid/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: Apologies, where comes before group by. Corrected the syntax.

Comment: `If you want to retrieve the sums for all users, then you need to use the result() method of your query results and get the weights in a loop.` surely not. This would be agonisingly inefficient. And it makes no sense to include a GROUP BY in that instance

Comment: @Strawberry the query already does the sums, result() method just retrieves the results. You do need the loop to process the sums.

Comment: I don't think you've reviewed your own query

Answer (score 0):

budy if i have two tables one for suppliers and other for their purchase invoices one to many relation.
and each supplier having many invoices and i want to get their dues what will be the query i used the following and getting results correct hope this will help you.

```
$this->db->select('supliers.SID,supliers.companyName, supliers.address, supliers.mobile, (sum(coalesce(suplierinvoice.newTotal,0)) - sum(coalesce(suplierinvoice.paidAmount, 0))) as dues ');
    $this->db->from('supliers');
    $this->db->join('suplierinvoice','suplierinvoice.suplierID = supliers.SID', 'left');
    $this->db->group_by('suplierinvoice.suplierID');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
```

The group_by will play its role for combining all those records which are related to same suplierID. if you want to get a single record just add where condition.